# Python Moviepy dropping CPU used FFMPEG

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

Would there be any specific reason why my CPU used will drop from 96%-100% 
to like 30% on average when running this script.

I want it to run @ 100% if possible to process the videos faster. Any help will do thanks in advance.

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate
import os, glob
from random import randint
from shutil import copyfile

def clipexport():

    video1 = mp.VideoFileClip(clips)
    Duration = video1.duration

    if "sin" in clips:

        try:
            startp = filename[filename.find("sin")+3:filename.find("sin")+6].strip()
            print(startp)
            if "}" in startp:
                startp = startp[:startp.find('}')]
                print(startp)
                start = int(startp)

            else:
                print(startp)
                start = int(startp)
        except:
            start = 0.35
            print('using default start value')

    else:
        start = 0.35
    print(start)

    if "sout" in clips:
        try:
            endp = filename[filename.find("sout")+4:filename.find("sout")+7].strip()
            print(endp)
            if "}" in endp:
                endp = endp[:endp.find('}')]
                print(endp)
                end = int(endp)

            else:
                print(endp)
                end = int(endp)

        except:
            end = Duration - 0.35
            print('using default end value')        

    else:
        end = Duration - 0.35

    print(Duration)
    print(end)
    trimmedvideo = mp.VideoFileClip(clips).subclip(start, end).resize(width=1920)
    trimmedvideo.write_videofile(exportPath, bitrate="8000k", threads="8")

def videocreator():

    calculateClips = 0

    for filename in os.listdir(newpath):
        print(filename)
        if ".mp4" in filename:

            calculateClips = calculateClips + 1

    calculateClips = calculateClips -1

    videolist = []
    videoLength = 0
    totalClips = 0

    for filename in os.listdir(newpath):

        print(filename + "Check Videos")

        if ".mp4" in filename:

            videolist.append(VideoFileClip(newpath + filename).crossfadein(1))

    final = concatenate(videolist, padding=-1, method="compose")
    final.write_videofile('myvideo.mp4', bitrate ='8000k', threads="8")

path = 'C:/TBD/TBD/#Frikkie/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '**') ):
    if "-" in infile:
        Refno = infile[infile.find('kie')+4:infile.find('-')].strip()

    else:
        Refno = infile[infile.find('kie')+4:].strip()

    print(Refno)
    clippath = infile + "/"
    length = len(clippath)
    #print(length)
    for clips in glob.glob( os.path.join(clippath, '**') ):
        #print(clips)
        filename = clips[clips.find(infile)+length:]
        filename = filename[:filename.find(".")]
        filename = filename + ".mp4"
        print(filename)
        exportPath = infile + "/" + "Export" + "/" + filename
        exportfolder = infile + "/" + "Export"
        print(exportfolder)
        if not os.path.exists(exportfolder):
            os.makedirs(exportfolder)

        try:

            if ".mp4" in clips:

                #clipexport()
                print("done mp4")
            elif ".m4v" in clips:
                #clipexport()
                print("done mp4")
            elif ".MOV" in clips:
                #clipexport()
                print("done mp4")
            else:
                continue


        except:

            print("Error")

    newpath = exportfolder + '/'
    newpath = newpath.replace('/', '\\')
    try:
        mp3number = str(randint(1,5))

        src = ("C:\music\{}.mp3".format(mp3number))
        dst = ("{}{}.mp3".format(newpath, mp3number))

        copyfile(src, dst)

    except:
        print("could not copy mp3")

    print("Mp3 Copied") 
    try:
        print("Video Path = " + newpath)
        videolist= []
        for filename in os.listdir(newpath):

            if "{" in filename:
                 newfilename = filename[:filename.find("{")].strip()
                 newfilename = newfilename + ".mp4"
                 oldfilename = newpath + filename
                 rename = newpath + newfilename
                 os.rename(oldfilename, rename)
                 videolist.append(newfilename)
            else:
                videolist.append(filename)

        for files in videolist:


            if files == "1.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "01.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "2.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "02.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "3.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "03.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "4.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "04.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "5.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "05.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "6.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "06.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "7.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "07.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "8.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "08.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

            elif files == "9.mp4":
                print(files)
                oldfilename = newpath + files
                rename = newpath + "09.mp4"
                os.rename(oldfilename, rename)

        print('done')

    except:
        print('not done')
    videocreator()
```

Comment: `threads="8"` is probably too low. For example `x264` uses 1.5 * logical cores by default. Either try removing the option to use the defaults or set the appropriate values based on codec.

Comment: Thanks aergistal even if i remove that option a 33 sec clip consisting of 3 clips only takes of 5 mins to export, My PC i am using has an i7 CPU 860 @ 2.8ghz with 12 gb memory and do have an SSD also. Anything Else i can try perhaps?

Comment: It would be useful to see what `ffmpeg` commands it execs. Any way to capture them?

Comment: Sort of a short version would be something like this

Comment: ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -f lavfi -r "30" -i "color=black:s=1920X1080:r=30" -filter_complex "[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va0]; [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10.18/TB[va1]; [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+27.009999999999998/TB[va2]; [3:v]scale=1920x1080,trim=duration=36.73[over]; [over][va0]overlay[over1]; [over1][va1]overlay[over2]; [over2][va2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" -vcodec libx264 -crf 19 -map [outv] T123456.mp4

Comment: Show the complete console output from that command as well. It is recommended to [edit] your question in include more information instead of attempting to cram everything into limited space comments.

Comment: @FrikkieMaritz How did you get the complete FFmpeg command that MoviePY uses?